# Identification of Quotient Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am trying to identify the ring $$\mathbb{Z}[X]/(2,x^2+1).$$

Since I know that $2\equiv x^2+1 \equiv 0 \ mod \ (2,x^2+1)$, could I identify this as $Z_2[i]$ or it does not have anything to do with this? If it is correct, how could be a good way for me to justify it?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a theorem which states that if $I\subseteq J$ are ideals of a ring $A$, then $A/J\cong A/I\Big/J/I$. You could use that to justify your claim, with, for instance, $I = x^2 + 2$ and $J = (2, x^2 + 2)$.

Comment: thank you, this is one of the Isomorphism Theorems, right?

Comment: Yes, it's called the [third ring isomorphism theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ThirdRingIsomorphismTheorem.html). At any rate, it is usually one of the first theorems that are proven in algebra texts once quotient rings are defined.

Answer (score 1):

You are right: this is $R=\Bbb Z_2[i]=\{a+bi:a,b\in\Bbb Z_2\}$
where $i^2=-1$. One can say more about this. As we are in characteristic
 $2$ then $-1=1$, so $i^2=1$. Then $(1+i)^2=1+2i+1=0$ so is a nilpotent.
Setting $u=1_i$, then $R=\Bbb Z_2[u]\cong \Bbb Z_2[X]/(X^2)$ where $u^2=0$.

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful!